# What is the type of undefined in javascript?

Tags: jquery

Can some body tell what is the type of undefined in JavaScript? What will typeof(undefined) return?

Comment: Why not just run that code and find out?

Comment: why don't you try it yourself... open the browser console and type `typeof(undefined) `

Comment: `typeof undefined` returns `"undefined"`

Comment: What happens if I press the letter to the left of W on my keyboard?  You're not gonna break the internet if you try it yourself :rolleyes:

Comment: @MDEV @MildlySerious @arun @reinstate They were asking what the type of undefined is, not what `typeof undefined` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What is undefined?**

In JavaScript there is Undefined (type), undefined (value) and undefined (variable).

*Type:*

> Undefined (type) is a built-in JavaScript type.

*Value:*

> Undefined (value) is a primitive and is the sole value of the
>   Undefined type. Any property that has not been assigned a value,
>   assumes the undefined value. (ECMA 4.3.9 and 4.3.10). A function
>   without a return statement, or a function with an empty return
>   statement returns undefined. The value of an unsupplied function
>   argument is undefined.

*Variable:*

> Undefined (variable) is a global property whose initial value is
>   undefined (value), Since its a global property we can also access it
>   as a variable. For consistency I’m always going to call it a variable
>   in this article.

*Null Distinction:*

> Undefined is distinct from null which is also a primitive value
>   representing the intentional absence of a value. The only similarity
>   between undefined and null is they both coerce to false.

**So what’s a ReferenceError?**

A ReferenceError indicates that an invalid reference value has been detected (ECMA 5 15.11.6.3)

In practical terms, this means a ReferenceError will be thrown when JavaScript attempts to get the value of an *unresolvable* reference.

Note how the message syntax varies across browser. As we will see none of these messages is particularly enlightening:

```
alert(foo);
//FF/Chrome: foo is not defined
//IE: foo is undefined
//Safari: can't find variable foo
```

Answer (score 0):

typeof(undefined) is "undefined" - see MDN's reference to [the typeof operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2Ftypeof)